# Bug with rollback that would affect the wrong revision

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, rollbacks

I have just tried to rollback [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47456692/revisions) from current revision 3 to old revision 2, in order to remove the [solved] title hack.

However, the page redraws without the rollback having been done. I've switched on my "persistent logs" in Firefox's Developer pane, and all AJAX calls seem to come back as 200, so I suspect some sort of bug that is not being reflected in the frontend. There also do not appear to be any JS errors in the browser console. I wonder that if there is a problem on the server side, it comes as a result of there not being any body to roll back?

Would someone (who is not a mod and has full edit privs) try this for me? If you can, please comment below to say that you are doing so first, rather than have several people try all at once!

I am on Firefox 56 on Linux Mint. I am using NoScript, but I have all domains whitelisted, as far as I can tell. I have used rollback a lot, with my current browser and configuration, so I'd be surprised if the problem was on my side.

Comment: Testing now (on this question).

Comment: I'm not seeing the effect you describe on this question. Are you on new-nav or anything like that? Your description of the rollback workflow sounds like it happens through Javascript, without loading a whole new page. That's not how rollbacks work for me.

Comment: I clicked "rollback" for "revision 2", but it changed it to revision 3. I'm sorry, I'll avoid more actions on this question. Chrome 61.0.3163.100 on MacOS.

Comment: I tried to rollback to revision 2 but it did absolutely nothing. Instead I tried a rollback to revision 4 (which is identical to revision 2) and it worked.

Comment: The problem seems to be that revision 3 was made by improving the suggested edit for revision 2. I managed to reproduce the problem in the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/revisions) by suggesting an edit with my sock puppet and approving it with my main account. Before making revision 195, I tried to rollback to revision 193 several times, but it didn't do anything. After making revision 195, I tried to rollback to revision 193 but it actually rolled back to revision 194 (even though it said "Rollback to Revision 193").

Comment: Thanks all. @user2357112 yes, clicking a rollback link for me is in JavaScript. It will usually do its work, and then perform a whole-page refresh to show the new state of the revisions page.

Comment: @Donald, aha! Sounds like you have reproduced it, thanks for doing that. Looks like you've got some details there that a developer could dig into.

Comment: No worries @Cœur, it looks like Donald has managed to create a test case.

Comment: Reminds me of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288734/295232) where instead of the title, the tags were edited. Because title, body and tags are stored in the database as separate revisions, the underlying problem could be the same.

Comment: DonaldDuck test case + Glorfindel linked case = it's not just "title" that is affected, it's any "improvement" done in addition to the approval of a suggested edit.

Comment: @Cœur: fair enough (feel free to edit the title here, you seem to have grokked it better than me).