# Make self-rollbacks trigger "edit removed during grace period"

Tags: feature-request, edits, grace-period

If you edit a post and then manually perform an inverse edit within 5 minutes, they get merged into a "null edit" with an "edit removed during grace period" message. On the other hand, if you edit a post and then hit rollback within 5 minutes, the edit and the rollback both show up in the edit log.

This difference is weird and confusing, and I don't think it's deliberate. It's a special case of the [general rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876) where rollbacks don't get grace-period-merged, but those general rules seem to be for cases like

- Qbert edits revision 2 to create revision 3
- Qbert rolls post back to revision 1, not revision 2

where the mechanics and edit message of a merged edit-rollback would be confusing.

The natural mechanism for "that edit was a mistake, I want to take it back" would be rollback, not manual un-editing. Can we get rollbacks to work like manual un-edits?

Comment: I think I probably know why, and I think I'm going to turn this into a feature request.

Comment: [Apparently there's already a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263752/lets-be-smarter-when-rolling-back-in-the-grace-period), languishing in meta.SE's giant bin of feature requests.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have this backwards; the "removed during grace period" feature was sort of an artifact of how edits coalesce during the grace period - at one time, [undoing the edit made it disappear from history entirely!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history)

This is a sort of compromise between not junking up the revision history and not confusing people about what happened.

But rollbacks are special. They're intentionally noisy.

And, yeah, that's not really much of an answer. But that's the best I can offer; this is how the system was implemented 10 years ago, and back then someone (lookin' at you, Jarrod...) decided that "edit" and "rollback" should be distinct, and they've remained distinct ever since; as a result, edits coalesce within a grace period; rollbacks do not. In effect, rollbacks never suffered from the "gaslighting" problem that we had to patch over with edits - they're *always* explicit about what was done.

This can actually be rather handy at times; if you *want* to avoid the grace period swallowing up an edit, you can make the edit and then revert via rollback to ensure that your changes remain in the revision history.

And if you think *that's* crazy... [It gets even weirder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41953/could-we-be-permitted-to-provide-a-reason-for-rolling-back)

Comment: hmm, looks like you wrote this up while I was writing up a question edit, so now the question and answer don't really match. That's always annoying.

Comment: Yeah. I re-wrote my answer to match your (new) question.

Comment: You may had to patch some issue with edits not affecting rollbacks, but I know an issue with rollbacks not affecting edits: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359783/bug-with-rollback-that-would-affect-the-wrong-revision